# How to read the barcode value from barcode scanner in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have connected the barcode scanner through the USB port and trying to display the barcode value in the textbox of an application. When i scanned the barcode it beep the sound but i am not able to see the barcode value in my application.

Comment: Is this asp.net OR Winforms?

Comment: @MattWilko, title said win forms but should not matter

Comment: Yes but it is tagged both - and it matters, you won't have access to the serial port from asp.net but you will in winforms for example

Comment: @MattWilko Bascially its in Winforms

Comment: I have removed the ASP.net tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually barcode scanners read the value and send the read data to computer like key strokes.

First, install the drivers of barcode scanner if any. Then

Can you try to open a notepad and try to read a barcode. If barcode comes to notepad, then just open a winforms project, use textbox, before reading barcode just focus to textbox

Comment: cheers, 2 correct answers lol

Answer (score 3):

USB Barcode readers, usually work in one of two ways:

1. They use keyboard wedge emulation (technically a software wedge emulating a keyboard wedge). i.e. the barcode scanned is received at the pc as though someone typed the string in on a keyboard. In this case you need to add a textbox to your form, make sure you have the focus set to it and scan something. You should then see the barcode value in the textbox.
2. They use a virtual serial (COM) port. If this is the case you need to use a [Serial port control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your form and intercept the [DataReceived event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

most barcode scanners act like a keyboard. cant review the link you sent as its blocked here.

best way IMO is to just add a textbox and have the scanner read into that.

some scanners can be programed to do things before entering the barcode, you could set up a shortcut key for the textbox and then have the scanner send that shortcut first so that every time you scan it will first set focus to the textbox then send the scan info