# Unable to find Windows.Devices.Enumeration and Windows.Storage.Streams

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, barcode-scanner

I need to use Windows.Storage.Streams and Windows.Devices.Enumeration in my Winforms application on Windows 7 to access and manipulate Barcode reader, but unable to find it to Add Reference. Not sure if can download it somewhere. I was able to find and download Microsoft.PointOfService and added reference to my project, but not the first two libraries.

Please advise.

Comment: Use google. Do a bit more research yourself before you ask someone else to help you.

Answer (score 3):

**How to access the Windows 10 APIs from WPF**

You can access the Windows 10 APIs from a pre-existing WPF project. To do so, go to your Solution Explorer window and …

- Right click on References.
- Select “Add Reference…” from the context menu.
- On the left of the Reference Manager, choose Browse and find the following file: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/UnionMetadata/Windows.winmd.
- Add it to your project as a reference. Note: You will need to change the filter to “All Files”.
- Right click on References. Select “Add Reference…” from the context menu. On the left of the Reference Manager, go to Browse and find the directory “C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/.NETCore/v4.5”. Add System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll to your project.

Learn More [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/)

Answer (score 2):

The [Windows.Storage.Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.aspx) and [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration) namespaces are part of the Windows Runtime. To use them you need to target Windows 8 or above. They aren't available when targeting Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be helpful to others that arrive here through Google, Microsoft has some NuGet packages to access Windows-specific APIs like that without the need to import or reference Windows libs manually. More info can be seen on their documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to use it from Windows 8/8.1, add a reference (like Sajeeb's answer) to the files at 32-bit `C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata` or 64-bit `C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata` respectively.

Answer (score -2):

I believe those namespaces are not part of Windows Apps libraries. I don't think a WinForm project is able to use them. Personally, I don't have newer versions of VS, so I am not sure of that. But there is supposed to be a new project type in VS2015 onwards.

Comment: Jai, any suggestion on what to use instead? VS2015 is exactly what I am using.

Comment: Like I said, I don't have VS2015 so I couldn't really try out anything. My guess is that if you definitely need those namespaces, you need to use Universal Window Platform. See this MSDN [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/getstarted), play around and look at the video.

But, I think UWP is multi-platform (PC/mobile etc), but it starts from Windows 8 onwards. So it may not be suitable for you since you need to run on Windows 7.

You can continue to google for other ways to interact with the barcode reader.

Comment: A simple search gave me [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809259/how-to-read-the-barcode-value-from-barcode-scanner-in-c-sharp-winforms), not sure if it's relevant to you.

Comment: I saw all that I was searching for it for 2 days straight, before asking  this question here. the best I could find was an example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner/cs), but it uses the libraries I was asking about as they are nowhere to be found on my Windows 7. But thanks anyway, I appreciate any support.